# Evaluating triple integral bound by ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this triple integral bound over an ellipsoid $E$:

$$\iiint_E (x^2+y^2+z^2)\, dx\, dy\, dz,$$

where $$E: \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} \le 1.$$

First I found the Jacobian which was $abc$, but now I have an integral over a sphere:

$$\iiint_S (a^2u^2+b^2v^2+c^2w^2)\, dw\, dv\, du.$$

Are the limits for each integral zero to one? If so I got $\frac{abc}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ but I am not sure if this is correct? Could anyone show me the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By $x=au$,$y=bv$ abd $z=cw$ we obtain

$$\int\int\int_E x^2+y^2+z^2 dx \,dy\, dz=\int\int\int_S (a^2u^2+b^2v^2+c^2w^2)\cdot (abc)\cdot dw\, dv\, du$$

but we can't integrate taking for each integral the bounds form zero to one since it is not a box but a sphere.

To integrate we can use for example [**spherical coordinates**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html).

Notabl to compute the integral we can use that

$$\int\int\int_S (a^2u^2+b^2v^2+c^2w^2)\cdot (abc)\cdot dw\, dv\, du=\\=a^3bc\int\int\int_S u^2 dw\, dv\, du+ab^3c\int\int\int_S v^2 dw\, dv\, du+abc^3\int\int\int_S w^2 dw\, dv\, du$$

and that by symmetry

$$\int\int\int_S u^2 dw\, dv\, du=\int\int\int_S v^2 dw\, dv\, du=\int\int\int_S w^2 dw\, dv\, du$$

and since

$$\int\int\int_S u^2 dw\, dv\, du=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^1 \rho^4\sin^3\phi\cos^2\theta \  d\rho d\phi d\theta=\frac4{15} \pi$$

we obtain

$$\int\int\int_S (a^2u^2+b^2v^2+c^2w^2)\cdot (abc)\cdot dw\, dv\, du=\frac{4\pi abc}{15}(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

Comment: How could I do this?

Comment: @JamesO'dare In cartesian we can assume $-1\le u\le 1$, $-\sqrt{1-u^2}\le v \le \sqrt{1-u^2}$ and  $-\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}\le w \le \sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}$.

Comment: $u=\rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$?

Comment: @JamesO'dare As an alternative yes you can also use spherical coordinates.

Comment: What would the limits be if I used spherical coordinates?

Comment: @JamesO'dare In this case we have $0\le r \le 1$, $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $0\le \phi\le \pi$. Refer to the link for more detail.

Comment: So would this be: $$\int \int \int a^2 (\rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta))^2+ b^2 ((\rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta))+c^2(\rho \cos(\phi)) (abc) \rho ^2 \sin(\phi) dp d\theta d\phi$$

Comment: @JamesO'dare It seems right. Maybe here it is convenient use symmetry and calculate $$a^3bc\int\int\int_S u^2 \cdot dw\, dv\, du$$ and from here obtain also the other two parts.

Comment: What symmetry did you use and how did you do that?

Comment: @JamesO'dare We can use that$$ \int\int\int_S (a^2u^2+b^2v^2+c^2w^2)\cdot (abc)\cdot dw\, dv\, du=a^3bc\int\int\int_S u^2 dw\, dv\, du+ab^3c\int\int\int_S v^2 dw\, dv\, du+abc^3\int\int\int_S w^2 dw\, dv\, du$$ and  $$\int\int\int_S u^2 dw\, dv\, du=\int\int\int_S v^2 dw\, dv\, du=\int\int\int_S w^2 dw\, dv\, du$$

Comment: I see that thank you! I got zero as the integrals is this expected?

Comment: It can’t be zero because all quantities are positive. I’ll add some more details on that.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically doing two changes of coordinates.

$$(abc)\int\int\int_S (a^2u^2+b^2v^2+c^2w^2 )dw dv du$$

Is what you get after you change $x=au$, $y=bv$, $z=cw$ and swap the (inside of) the ellipsoid $E$ for the ball $S$. (I like to reserve the word *sphere* for only the outside part $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$)

The easiest way to integrate over the region $S$ is with spherical coordinates.

$u=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta$

$v=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta$

$w=\rho\cos\phi$

This change of coordinates gives

$$(abc)\int\int\int_S (a^2u^2+b^2v^2+c^2w^2 )dw dv du$$
$$=(abc)\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^1 \left[a^2\rho^2\sin^2\phi\cos^2\theta+b^2\rho^2\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta+c^2\rho^2\cos^2\phi\right]\rho^2\sin\phi \  d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

The computation [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28abc%29%20*%20int%200%20to%202pi%20int%200%20to%20pi%20int%280%20to%201%29%20%5B%28a%20p%20sin%28phi%29cos%28theta%29%29%5E2%2B%28b%20p%20sin%28phi%29sin%28theta%29%29%5E2%2B%28c%20p%20cos%28phi%29%29%5E2%5D%20p%5E2%20sin%28phi%29%20dp%20dphi%20dtheta) gives that this integral is $\frac{4\pi abc}{15}(a^2+b^2+c^2)$. I am not sure if this is correct, as I did not do it by hand myself. However, the answer is symmetric with respect to the triple $(a,b,c)$ so I think it is correct.

Also, you should not expect zero since you're integrating a function that is positive everywhere except the origin.

Comment: Thank you very much!